everybody body is different, but is 5 months enough to see visual changes?
I know I sound desperate to see visual changes, but I have been training for 5 months, 4 days a week program, bulking, eating good, and my weight has increased by 10kg in the last 5 months, the weight in the gym is increasing for most exercises, however I don't see muscles popping up on my body, and I was wondering, am I being impatient? or is there another factor?
I use raider program by bald omni man using boostcamp app. have been using it for a week, before that i used to do full body workout 3 days a week.
Thanks.

You gained 10kg. Where did that go? It's hard to hide 10kg.

@DaveLiepmann It feels like it is all fats, but seriously, can you possibly get stronger without building muscles, or is that logically not possible? i hope it is the latter

"Muscles Popping" happens when your total bodyfat percentage goes down to a certain point. It's common that bodyfat and muscle increase at the same time, thus your total bodyfat percentage does not decrease.
So while you're eating and training better, the 10kg gain is most likely not entirely lean tissue. Your muscles are certainly bigger, but it's being covered by a layer of fat.
However, don't get too discouraged. Progress is a lot like growing up. It's slow and you see yourself every day, so it's harder for you to notice changes. I would imagine if you took a photo of yourself 5 months ago and compared yourself to a photo of yourself today, then you'd probably see a fairly dramatic difference.
You're still relatively new to working out, and you are making progress. If you're calorie counting then I'd probably slow down the eating a little bit. Try to shoot closer to a 0.25kg per week gain. If not then I would just try to remain consistent, and learn to enjoy the process. A lot of people will recommend caloric deficits and all that, but I personally believe that unless you're obese, you're better off as a beginner just making better food choices, and focus on training. It's a plan that's generally a lot easier to adhere to, and it builds long-term habits.
